# Clear the default value in a textearea

Tags: html, textarea

I realize an instant messenger where I have a textearea with marked at the beginning "Write your message ..."

I want that when the user clicks in this textarea, this message is erased. Is it possible to do this in HTML?

I tried to use onFocus but it does not work.

```
<textarea class="chat-input"
              rows="2" cols="50"
              (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)"
              onfocus="if(this.value=='Write your message ...'){this.value='';}"
              onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Write your message ...';}">
      Write your message ...
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `placeholder` attribute.

```html
<textarea 
placeholder="Write your Message"></textarea>
```

If you want to hide placeholder on focus

```html
<textarea 
data-placeholder="Write your Message" 
placeholder="Write your Message" 
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
onblur="this.placeholder = this.getAttribute('data-placeholder')"></textarea>
```